# dotenv は production 環境では推奨されない?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

dotenv という gem があります。(https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) この gem は、たとえば rails_root の直下に .env というファイルを置いておくと、その値を ruby で環境変数を取り扱う値である `ENV` に取り込んでくれます。

この dotenv という gem、便利なのですが、 github リポジトリの README.md の最初の文に次のように書いてあります。

> Shim to load environment variables from `.env` into `ENV` in *development*.

dotenv の gem の説明で、 *development* をとりたてて協調しているということは、おそらくこれは production で利用されることは想定していないないし、推奨されないのではないかと思っています。

#### 質問

- dotenv を production で利用することによって、何か予期される問題などありますでしょうか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[dotenvのFAQ](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#frequently-answered-questions) に回答がありました。

超意訳ですが、「PuppetやChefによる`/etc/environment`の設定やheroku configなど、一般的なより良い方法があるけど、 `.env.production` や `.env.test` など使うのもありだよ。でも、 production用の.envファイルはコミットしないように気をつけましょう。」という感じでしょうか。